# Receiving port SMS android?

Tags: android, sms, port

I am developing an app which receives port sms.
Though I am not able to receive the sms yet.

The permission specified in the manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
</uses-permission>
```

The broadcast receiver in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".BinarySMSReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:port="80"
                android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The broadcast receiver class

```
public class BinarySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (null != bundle) {
        // String info = "SMS from ";
        String info = "SMS from ";
        String sender = "";
        String sms = "";
        // String info = "";

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        byte[] data = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            sender += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            // info += "\n*****BINARY MESSAGE*****\n";
            info += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + "\n";

            data = msgs[i].getUserData();

            for (int index = 0; index < data.length; ++index) {
                info += Character.toString((char) data[index]);
                sms += Character.toString((char) data[index]);
            }
        }
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

        db.addSMS(new SMS(sender, sms));

        Intent i = new Intent(context, SMSListActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                i, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("PORT SMS")
                // Vibration
                .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                // LED
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()

                .bigText(info)).setContentText(info);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(2, mBuilder.build());
        Log.e("msgg   ", info);
        // t.setText(info);
        Toast.makeText(context, info, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
  }
```

Am i missing here something in the manifest?

Comment: What are you listening for on port 80? That is, are you sending the test SMS from another of your apps? If so, are you sure they're being sent correctly?

Comment: I am sending the test sms form api on port 80

Comment: Do you have an Activity in your Receiver app?

Comment: On receiving the message I display a notification. And on the click of the notification I move the user to activity.

Comment: Until you launch the app at least once after installation, it is in a _stopped_ state, and your Receiver won't work. Run you're Activity once, then test your SMS. (This is assuming you're running on a version of Android > 3.0, but most people are.)

Comment: I am already doing like that only. But still not receiving sms

Comment: OK. Just making sure. I couldn't tell from your description. Anyway, I just copied/pasted your code, and it works for me. I can think of a few possibilities: 1) Your manifest is wrong; maybe permission in the wrong place. 2) You're not sending correctly, somehow. 3) Port 80 on your Receiver device is being used by another app aborting the broadcast, if that's possible with data SMS; I'm not sure. Port 80, btw, is a common port for MMS. You might try a different port.

Comment: Do you know how to send port SMS from a GSM modem? I think there might be some problem with the API I am using.

Comment: Which package are you importing? It should be `android.telephony.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your priority in manifest

```
 <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
```

After that if you face any problem follow [this](http://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/227-handle-sms-on-android) link

Comment: The link explains about the text sms and not port SMS. A port SMS is received to a specific port specified in an application not in the inbox.